# Sets of Consecutive primes that can be split in equal parts

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Consider the following sequence of primes: 5,7,11,13,17,19. We can split this sequence between 13 and 17 so that 5+7+11+13=17+19.
Can we find such sequences of arbitrary large length? Or even sequences that can be split into arbitrary many equal sums?  I would think this is quite similar to having arbitrary large arithmic progressions, thus I'd suspect this property for any set whose reciprocals diverge. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure...you can use Szemeredi's Theorem to get arbitrarily long progressions, and then remark that there are infinitely many pairs of natural numbers $(n,m)$ with $n(n-1)=2m(m-1)$.  Of course the example you gave isn't of that type...and the primes that Szemeredi gives you are certainly not consecutive.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's consistent both with heuristics and with what we know that infinitely often, the initial sequences of primes $\{2,3,5,\dots,p_n\}$ can be split between two of its primes to form parts with equal sums.

Comment: If we search a sequence of length 2k+1, the sum of 2k+1 prime numbers is odd, except if this sequence starts with 2. So, for a sequence with odd length, we will generally not find any solution.

Comment: @BobLangefeld FYI, a somewhat similar previous question is [Proof of a theorem expressing every prime number as a linear combination with $\pm 1$ coefficients of the previous prime numbers](/q/4541500).

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks. I looked but that  question would also work for the fibonacci sequence right?  I think mine is true because of the log growth rate, similar to the Erdos conjecture on arithmic progressions.

Comment: @BobLangefeld You're welcome. Yes, the other question would also basically work for the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) because, as I indicated in my [comment](/questions/4541500/proof-of-a-theorem-expressing-every-prime-number-as-a-linear-combination-with#comment9548971_4541500) there, any [complete sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_sequence#Other_complete_sequences) can be used, with one or two appropriate adjustments, instead of the consecutive prime numbers.